# Select statement MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a simple select statement on a mysql database. In MsSql it works fine, but I can't get it to work in MySql.

What I want to do is the following:

Lets say I have a table (named TestTable) like this:

```
ID     |  DOMAIN             |  NrOfVisitors
--------------------------------------------
1      | something.com       | 435
--------------------------------------------
2      | blabla.com          | 231
```

And I have a string, like `http://bla.ttt.something.com/blabla`

Now I want to pass in the string, and select the rows where the domain is in the string.
In MsSQL I can do the following:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM TestTable 
    WHERE "http://bla.ttt.something.com/blabla" LIKE "%" DOMAIN "%"
```

But in MySql it returns `0` rows. WHat am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should extract the host first. That will make the lookup easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE "http://bla.ttt.something.com/blabla" LIKE CONCAT("%",DOMAIN,"%")
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the first step for a robust solution would be to extract the domain from the string (using [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) ):

```
$string = 'http://bla.ttt.something.com/blabla';
$domain = parse_url($string, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Then, assuming you want to match on the top two levels of the domain only (`something.com`), you need to extract that from the domain...

```
$parts = explode('.', $domain);
$top2parts = array_slice($parts, -2);
$rootDomain = implode('.', $top2parts);
```

Then, we build the query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM TestTable 
    WHERE domain LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($rootDomain)."%'";
```

That should do it for you.  For the input given, it'll generate:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM TestTable 
    WHERE domain LIKE '%something.com%'
```

Of course you could do it the other way, and search by concating wildcards to the domain:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM TestTable 
    WHERE CONCAT('%', domain, '%') LIKE 'http://bla.ttt.something.com/blabla'
```

But the problem with that is shown by the sample URL: `http://foo.bar/blah/something.com.html`...  Which will return a false positive for `something.com` since it's in the URL, but it's not in the domain...  So, one method of avoiding that (while still searching for the full domain) would be to do a combination:

```
$string = 'http://bla.ttt.something.com/blabla';
$domain = parse_url($string, PHP_URL_HOST);
$sql = "SELECT * 
    FROM TestTable 
    WHERE CONCAT('%', domain, '%') LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($domain)."'";
```

Which for this case will generate:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM TestTable 
    WHERE CONCAT('%', domain, '%') LIKE 'bla.ttt.something.com'
```